# Given a sound sample, how do I double its frequency

Tags: audio

if I have a sound file in .dat format, that looks like this

```
; Sample Rate 22050
0.0 -0.0390625
4.5351473922902495E-5   -0.0390625
9.070294784580499E-5    -0.0390625
1.3605442176870748E-4   -0.0390625
```

Where the left column is the second and the right column is the amplitude (-1.0 to 1.0)
How do I double the frequency of the sound? Could someone give me the big picture of it?
My understanding is that the frequency is how many times the sound is repeated over second. So if I halve all the value in the second column, does that double the frequency?

Thank you

Comment: The right column is confusing - it looks like it's a flat curve with a ll amplitude values the same, meaning it will be silent.

Answer (score 3):

To double the frequency, you want to halve every value in the left column. This will make any given part of the sound take half as much time, which is the same as saying the frequency is doubled.

Comment: If I do that, that means the sound only last half as long right? Is there any way to double the frequency while still having the same length?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Use the same data and double the sample rate, or use the same samplerate and remove every other sample.
Any method you use would result in the sound only last for half as long. A dirty trick for working around this is to repeat a set amount of samples to make up for it.